GLMM for Inference vs Prediction
I am assessing cross-sectional repeated measures data using a mixture of linear mixed models (LMM) and Generalized Linear Mixed Models (GLMM).  I see in various places that GLMM is used primarily for prediction of outcome variable values.  My research is primarily to infer relationships between a set of independent variables and an outcome variable (inference) rather than prediction of values.  Is GLMM still appropriate to use with continuous/approximately-continuous outcomes when the goal is inference over prediction?

Please edit the question to provide more context and to provide links to the references ("various places") that suggest a difference between LMM and GLMM in this regard. It also would help to say more about the substance of your study; sometimes there are ways to analyze all the data together that might be preferable to the separate models you seem to be using.

Is "yes" a detailed enough answer? In my experience, GLMM is used primarily for inference.

Seconding @EdM, I am always interested in seeing the links when people read stuff "in various places". I have personally thought about GLMMs as mainly an inferential tool. Where are people saying that it's used primarily for prediction ... ???

Yes is good enough. I am using GLMM with robust estimation to compare with LMM results using automated syntax, both with an eye to inferencing the impact of a series of predictors on a series of outcomes. Thank you!
